# Dynamically switch between views in Power BI using slicers

Tags: powerbi

I have two slicers in Power BI:
The first slicer is used to select between D (daily) and W (weekly) views. Below is the DAX formula for the first slicer:

```
SlicerTable = DATATABLE (
    "SlicerSelection", STRING,
    {
        { "D" },
        { "W" }
    }
)
```

The second slicer is used to select the list of dates (when D is selected on the first slicer) or list of weeks (when W is selected on the first slicer). Below is the DAX formula for the second slicer:

```
Dynamic Date/Week Selection = 
VAR SelectedValue = SELECTEDVALUE('SlicerTable'[SlicerSelection])
RETURN
    IF(
        SelectedValue = "D",
        SELECTEDVALUE('DatesParameter'[Date]),
        SELECTEDVALUE('WeeksParameter'[Week])
    )
```

The problem is that the second slicer is not showing the list of dates or weeks, it shows blank. Can someone please help?

Below is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot switch the source of a slicer dynamically.

Since you have two separate tables for `Date` and `Week` - you will need to have a slicer for each. Then you could create two bookmarks:

1. Days shown, Weeks hidden, and call it "D".
2. Days hidden, Weeks shown, and call it "W".

Then you can use the button navigator to create you bookmark switch (very similar to your first slicer, which you won't need anymore). You can find in the Insert tab in the ribbon, Buttons > Navigator > Bookmark navigator.

There is one other option - having one table column with both Days and Weeks then using a measure to filter on D or W for that slicer. Share what your `'DatesParameter'[Date]` and `'WeeksParameter'[Week]` tables look like, and we can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wasn't aware that you couldn't dynamically switch the source of a slicer. I think I'll go with the first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Dynamic Date/Week Selection = 
 VAR SelectedValue = SELECTEDVALUE('SlicerTable'[SlicerSelection])
 RETURN
     SWITCH(
         SelectedValue,
         "D", SELECTEDVALUE('DatesParameter'[Date]),
         "W", SELECTEDVALUE('WeeksParameter'[Week]),
         BLANK()
     )
```

This DAX formula uses SWITCH to handle the "D" and "W" cases explicitly and return the corresponding values. If neither case is matched, it returns BLANK().

After making sure that your data model, relationships, and DAX measures are set up correctly, your second slicer should display the list of dates or weeks based on the selection in the first slicer.

Or tell me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: It's still returning blank

Comment: Then you will need to have a slicer for each as @Sam Nseir discussed above.

Comment: thanks that's what I ended up doing.